# How to make part of a project open source?

Tags: open-source

Suppose you have a large multi-service integrated project . You suddenly decide to make one of those services open source. How would you do it without leaking the other parts?

For example, releasing the whole repository of a service may not work, since the sketch of other services had once resided in this repository, and were separated afterwards.

Also, what would you do about those parts related to "integrity". You may have two components A and B, which collaborate, but you want only to open-source A. What would you do with the B-related code?

Good examples of how others have achieved alike goals would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When releasing software as open-source, you need to decide for the license. There are several popular approved open-source licenses. The OSI approves licenses and you should not choose a non-approved license or design your own license if you want your work to be adopted by others:
http://opensource.org/licenses/category

When releasing your software package A under open-source license X, you are not obliged to follow the terms of the license yourself. You retain the copyright to package A, and even if others who license the software from you were not allowed to distribute a combined version of A with a non-free package B, you can still do this.

However, open-sourcing is only useful if package A is still of use without having package B at hand, and/or if you want others to contribute to A. As soon as others contribute to A, you start sharing the copyright on parts of A with them. Effectively, if they contribute back under license X to you, you will not be allowed anymore to distribute a combination of A and B without their specific consent (effectively giving you an individual license).

Now lets see what options you have:

- Publish package A under a **permissive** license Y. The BSD license is the most prominent example of such a license. This license allows everybody to combine A with any non-free package B. It also allows everybody to re-license A to others under non-free terms. It is up to you to decide if you have a problem with this or not. Example software released under such license: X.org display server, LLVM compiler, Mach kernel (used in OS X), BSD operating systems.
- Publish package A under a **strict non-permissive** license X. The GNU GPL v2/v3 licenses are the most prominent examples. Re-distribution of package X is only allowed under the same or an equivalent license. The software cannot be linked to software of a non-equivalent license and redistributed. (Linking A and B by itself is allowed, but not the distribution). You can link GPL software with BSD software because then the BSD software becomes GPL-licensed in your distribution (as BSD license allows this). To still profit from the contribution of outsiders, use a **copyright agreement** where these parties give you full copyright on their contributions. So you can still distribute packages A, B under a non-GPL license yourself, even if A contains code from others. Example software that does this: MySQL.
- Publish package A under a not so strict **non-permissive** license Z. The GNU LGPL v2/v3 licenses are the most prominent examples. These licenses behave like the ones above with the specific exception that it is allowed to link package A to any non-LGPL software and distribute. Licensees are not allowed to redistribute your work under non-LGPL terms but they are allowed to combine it with non-free software, e.g. via a plug-in system. Most projects that use this license are essentially libraries and not end-user software. So you can use these libs in your non-free projects. Prominent examples: Qt, Webkit (used in Chrome and Safari).

The question when choosing a solution is essentially: How much freedom do you want to give others on their use of package A? The more freedom you give, the more likely you will find adoption and also contributions back to your project. However in the most permissive form, you open the door for people who only benefit from your work on A, maybe compete with you, and not give back to your and/or the public at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I am looking for is the technical "how to".